# Will Bitcoin mining stop?

Tags: mining-theory

According to this [site](https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/how-many-bitcoins-are-there/) there are 3,260,162.5 bitcoins left to be mined. Do you know if eventually Bitcoin mining will stop after that? If yes which other cryptocurrency can be mined for ever?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The discontinuation of newly mined bitcoins does not mean that there will be no block rewards. Block rewards come from confirmed transaction fees also.